# How to get previous 2 years data in OBIEE 11g analysis

Tags: obiee

When I click year prompt, It must display both current year along with previous 2 years data in OBI 11g (Analysis).

eg., when I click 2015 in prompt, It must display 2015,2016 and 2014's data.

Could anyone of you suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many options. Fastest = presentation variable + analysis filter:

```
"Time"."Year" >= @{pv_Year}{2017} - 2 AND "Time"."Year" <= @{pv_Year}{2017}
```

This of course assumes that your "Year" is a numeric value and not a string.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it has to be done on dynamic ,not static.

Comment: That IS dynamic. It uses a presentation variable which is set by the prompt. Hard to be more dynamic that that.